# Source documents are not mapped: Issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, data-migration-tool

When I'm using:-

php bin/magento migrate:settings  vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/config.xml

```
Then getting following error:-


[2018-09-20 13:33:44][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped: core_store,core_store_group,core_website
[2018-09-20 13:33:44][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: store,store_group,store_website

  [Migration\Exception]
  Integrity Check failed
```

Already mapped this into file "map.xml.dist" like:-

```
<ignore>
         <document>core_store</document>
  </ignore>
```

**Here is my config.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
   <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento1-db" user="myuser" password="mypassword"/>
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento2-db" user="myuser" password="mypassword"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.8/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.4/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.3.8</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key>57ac2319af8097f113b621b444e0a111</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

Also R&D & apply various solution but it doesn't work.

I'm using fresh Magento2.2.5 version.& my Magento1 version is Magento1.9.3.8

Please help me to fix this issue.it's very urgent.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please add config. Xml  file

Comment: @Rutvee,added,please check.

Answer (score 2):

Some changes needed in your config:

please make your config like below:

```
     <source>
<database host="localhost" name="magento1" user="root" password=""/>
    </source>
 <destination>
<database host="localhost" name="magento2" user="root" password=""/>
</destination>
     <options>
<map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/map.xml</map_file>
<eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
<eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
<eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
<log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
<log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
<settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
<customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
<customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
<delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
<order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
<map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
<class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>
<tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
<stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file> 
<customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>

<!--
In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
-->
<bulk_size>100</bulk_size>
<!--
Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
 -->
<direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
<source_prefix></source_prefix>
<dest_prefix></dest_prefix>
<auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
<log_file>migration.log</log_file>
<progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
<upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
<edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
<edition_number>1.9.2.4</edition_number>
<init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
<init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
<crypt_key>f5b73dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(Your magento1.9.3.0's crypt key)</crypt_key>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! my config.xml is fine there was some problem in Magento2 DB.

Comment: How to migrate the custom modules data?

Comment: Just make schema for it and import data by downloading manually

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, yes same issue for me also, I have edited my config.xml with source and destination details.